# Is it possible to listen for function calls in C# (i.e. treat C# function calls as events)?

Tags: c#

I would like to log when functions in my app are called. Is there a way I can listen for functions called and run code on such events?

If so, where do I start looking at how to do this?

Comment: Why not just add your calls to your logging methods inside your functions?

Comment: I do in certain functions, but it would now be useful to log start and end timestamps of all functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to scatter your methods with `log`, consider using an AOP(Aspect Oriented Programming) library to do so.

[Here](https://ayende.com/blog/3474/logging-the-aop-way) is a blog illustrating this.

Comment: Thank you - I am looking for an aspect orientated approach and that blog looks useful

Answer (score 4):

Just do the work to insert your logging directly where you want it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        logger.Information("Something happened");
    }
}
```

This will allow you to customize the logging needs to your class - especially if you use something like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) in concert with [SEQ](https://getseq.net/).

I doubt the Aspect Oriented Logging approach will really allow you to get a nice useful semantic logging experience.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do this for?  Is it for performance profiling, or because you want to execute something when (for example) a function has been called x times?

If its for performance profiling, if you're using Visual Studio, the IDE has some built-in profiling functions.  Under the "Debug" menu, there is the "performance Profiler" (Alt+F2).  Running that on your application can give you a lot of detail about what is being called, how many time, how much CPU load etc etc.  Particularly useful if you generate the "Create Detail Report" once it has run.

It's a bit hard to interpret, but if you're interested in how much time is being spent doing various functions in your application, it can be very useful.